# If $a=7!$, $b=_{13}P_k$, $\frac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}=120$, find the $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

> Question:
>
> $a=7!$, $b=_{13}P_k$, $\dfrac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}=120$, then find the $k$.

My attempts:

$$\frac{ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}=\gcd{(a,b)}=120$$

$\gcd{(7!, _{13}P_k)}=120 \Longrightarrow \begin{cases} \dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!}\in \mathbb {Z^+} \\ \dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 2≠0 \\
\dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 3≠0 \\
\dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 7≠0  \end{cases} \Longrightarrow \begin{cases} 
\dfrac{13×12×\cdots (13-k+1)!}{120} \in \mathbb {Z^+} \\ 
 \dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 2≠0 \\
\dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 3≠0 \\
\dfrac{13!}{(13-k)!×5!} \mod 7≠0  \end{cases} \Longrightarrow 13-k+1=10 \Longrightarrow k=4$

Is my solution correct? Do I have any missing or unnecessary/unneeded steps?

Comment: I think you mean ${}^{13}C_k$

Comment: What do you denote by ${}_{13}P_k$? It it the same as ${13\choose k}$?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin permutation coefficient

Comment: @Elementary There is no solution to your problem as you stated it how it is now.

Comment: @JanEerland why?

Comment: @Elementary Because the only possible solutions to $\text{lcm}\left(7!,\binom{13}{\text{k}}\right)\ne0$ gives $\text{k}\in\left\{0,1,\dots,12,13\right\}$ and none of these gives $\frac{7!\cdot\binom{13}{\text{k}}}{\text{lcm}\left(7!,\binom{13}{\text{k}}\right)}=120$.

Comment: @JanEerland This is a permutation coefficient.

Comment: .... Oh, I guess $_{13}P_k = \frac {13!}{(13-k)!}$.... isn't it?

Comment: @fleablood please look https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.u.arizona.edu/~kuchi/Courses/MAT167/Files/LH_LEC.0320.Prob.Perms.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiijtT156fqAhU9i8MKHe07D6UQFjAKegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1tO4krrt7k_lAx9Bst25KL

Comment: No.... I had a brain fart.  I thought about the *arithmetic* and "bottom term" rather than the *number of terms*.   If we have $\omega = (N+1)......M=(M-(k-1)......M = \frac {M!}{N!}=\frac {M!}{(M-k+1)!}$.  We have to product of all terms after the $N$ term to the $M$, OR another way of thinking of it is we have $k$ terms up to $M$.  ... Brain fart.  I find the "starting point" ($N+1$) more basic than the number of terms ($k$) that I farted on remembering how *permutations* are defined by number of terms.... ooops... *red*...  (still think my logic in my answer is easier than yours).

Answer (score 1):

**This was based on the original post**

The problem as stated is incorrect or there is a typo. If $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}=120$, then that would mean $\text{lcm}(a,b)=120$. But $120=\text{lcm}(a,b) \geq a=7!$. This is not possible.

**After the original post got modified:**

Perhaps, the $\gcd(a,b)=120$. In which case we can do the following:
\begin{align*}
\gcd(a,b)&=120\\
\gcd(7!,b)&=120\\
\gcd\left(42,\frac{b}{120}\right)&=1
\end{align*}
This means $\frac{b}{120}$ is (at least) not divisible by $2,3$ and $7$, where  $b=\frac{13!}{(13-k)!}$. We know that $13!=2^{10} \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^{1} \dotsb$. So
$$\frac{b}{120}=\frac{13!}{(2^3\cdot 3 \cdot 5) \, (13-k)!}=\frac{2^{7} \cdot 3^4\cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^{1} \dotsb}{(13-k)!}$$

This means our $k$ should be such that the prime factorization of $(13-k)!$ should also have exactly these powers of the primes $2,3$ and $7$.

Since $2$ should only appear with exponent $7$ in the prime factorization of $(13-k)!$, so $13-k \geq 8 \implies k \leq 5$ and $13-k \leq 9 \implies k \geq 4$.

Since $3$ should only appear with exponent $4$ in the prime factorization of $(13-k)!$, so $13-k \geq 9 \implies k \leq 4$.

Thus $\color{red}{k=4}$ will satisfy the gcd condition.

Comment: \lcm doesnt work in MathJax

Comment: Thank you. I fixed. There is a typo.

Comment: @Elementary I have added some steps after you **modified** the problem.

Comment: So, Are my attempts  sufficient?

Comment: @Elementary I think there is some required details missing (which actualy forms the core of the problem) as to how did you conclude that $13-k+1=10$ from those (non-)congruences?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin  Thank you.  I noticed this in my edited question.

Comment: This is a fact: If $13-k+1<10$ Then, our modular conditions fail.

Comment: @Elementary You have to *justify* that fact. Because $\frac{13!}{(13-k)! 5!}=\frac{13\cdot 12 \dotsb (13-k+1)}{5!}$, so you still have a $5!$ in the denominator, which requires some explanation to reach your conclusion.

Comment: do you agree with me if $13−k+1<10$ then we have $13×12×⋯{\color{red}{×9}}×⋯ $ which contradicts with modular conditions and $13−k+1>10$ then bis not positive integer. So we conclude $13−k+1=10$

Comment: Why a downvote? The method is correct in my opinion. If you have an issue with the method, then please point it out so that either it can be improved or you can be convinced that everything is okay and OP gets the benefit as well.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Not downvote.

Comment: @Elementary This is not for you in particular. It is for the unknown person who did this :-)

Comment: Do you agree with my argument? Why I conclude $k=4$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be simpler to do this:

$\frac {ab}{\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)}=\gcd(a,b)$ so we have

$\gcd(7!, b) = 120$

So $\gcd(2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot 7, b) = 2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

So $3|b$ but $9\not \mid b$ and $8|b$ but $16\not\mid b$ and $5|b$ and $7\not \mid b$.

$b =13*(13-1)*....*(13-(k-1))= \prod_{m=13-k+1}^{13} m$. Let $L = 13-k+1$ If $L \le 9$ then $9|b$.  So $L>9$.  If $10 < L < 15$ then $5\not \mid b$ so $L\le 10$.  So $L = 10$.

So $13- k+1=10$ and $k=4$.

But we must verify that $L=10$ is acceptable namely that $3|b$ (which is does as $3|12$) that $9\not \mid b$ (which it doesn't as $12$ is the only multiple of $3$ between $10$ and $13$ inclusively) that $8|b$ but $16\not \mid b$ (as $2|10$ and $4|12$ and $10, 12$ are the only two even numbers between $10$ and $13$ that is fine) and that $5|b$ (which as $5|10$ it does) and the $7\not \mid b$ (which as there are no multiples of $7$ between $10$ and $13$ it does not.

Comment: do you agree with me  if $13−k+1<10$ then we have $13×10×⋯×{\color{red}{9}}×⋯$ which contradicts with modular conditions and $13−k+1>10$ then $ b $is not positive integer. So we conclude $13-k+1=10$

Comment: $k=10?????????$

Comment: No, I don't.! If $_{13}P_k = (k+1) *..... * 13$ and we have that the *greatest* common factor is $120$ then because $9$ *does* divide $7!$ we can't have $9|_{13}P_k$.  So $k \ge 9$.  What's your definition of $_{13}P_k$?

Comment: This is a permutation coefficient . $_{13}P_k= 13×...(13-k+1)$

Comment: Oh.... so it is... It's the number of ways to pick $k$ elements from $13$ isn't it.

Comment: It's an irritating convention.  As $\frac {M!}{N!} = (N+1)......M$ it's make more sense to me to describe the value in terms of $M$ and $n$ rather than it terms of $M$ and then number of terms taken. (Of course the number of terms taken $K$ are so that $K=M-N+1$ and $N = M-K +1$).  I tend to forget that the combinatorics meaning is "take $K$ choices from $M$"..... well, maybe I *don't* tend to make that mistake... today may (or may not) have been the first time I made the mistake. But if $_{13}P_k = (M+1).....13$, I still claim $M=10$. I said that before my error, I say it now after the error.

Comment: @fleablood Interesting way, but I am not sure if I would call it simpler because you are doing the same analysis but slightly differently.